# Noise sensitivity to output impedances

Tags: mosfet, noise, inverter, cmos

> A lower value of output impedance in a CMOS inverter leads to less sensitivity to noise of the inverter.

Can someone elaborate regarding this?

The quote comes from *Digital Integrated Circuits* by Rabaey in the CMOS inverter chapter.

Comment: A lower value of output impedance assuming what stays constant? Overdrive? g_m? device sizing?

Comment: Does this answer your question?:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/606237/effect-of-impedance-on-noise-immunity